# return outside of function (react-native)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

hello everyone i try to run this tuturial https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html in my app but i have some error.

[image: this is my error]

my code is :

```
          import React, {Component} from 'react';
          import ReactNative from 'react-native';
          import * as firebase from 'firebase';
          const StatusBar = require('./components/StatusBar');
          const ActionButton = require('./components/ActionButton');
          const ListItem = require('./components/ListItem');
          const styles = require('./styles.js');

          _renderItem(item)
                     {
                       return(
                               <ListItem item="{item}" 
                                       onpress="{()"  ==""> {}}/>
                               );
                      }
```

Comment: Your code is not complete. Refer this completed project https://github.com/davideast/firebase-react-native-sample/blob/master/index.ios.js

Answer (score 0):

In React you do not have to put quotes on dynamic parameters:

```
<ListItem item={item} onpress={() => {}}/>
```

I don't know how you came to have : `"{()"  ==""> {`. Maybe a copy/past bad behavior...

Comment: thnx Damien Leroux for you answer but still give me the same error

Comment: _renderItem(item)
 {
 return(
      <ListItem item={item} onpress={()==>{}}/>
    );
  }

  render() 
{
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <StatusBar title="Grocery List>

        <ListView datasource={this.state.dataSource} renderrow={this._renderItem.bind(this)} style={styles.listview}/>

        <ActionButton title="Add" onpress={() ==> {}} />

      </View>
    );
  }

Comment: Please provide a formatteed code in your original question :(. Otherwise `onpress={() ==> {}} ` cant work. it is `onpress={() => {}} `